Type mismatch when accumulating errors with Arrow-Kt
I'm working on a function to process a list of File objects. My plan was to use the 'mapOrAccumulate()' function from Arrow to get the collected errors if one or more files fails to process. However my code is failing to build with the compilation error:

Type mismatch. Required: IdocsFileInfo Found: Either<kotlin.Error /* =
java.lang.Error */, IdocsFileInfo>

I have looked through the documentation and examples and I just can't wrap my head around what is causing this issue. Any help would be apprciated.
My code:
fun mapServiceDocs(orderedFilesForPerson:List<File>): Either<NonEmptyList<Error>, List<IdocsFileInfo>>{
       return orderedFilesForPerson.mapOrAccumulate<Error, File, IdocsFileInfo>{ file:File->

            file.buildDocument()
        }
}

fun File.buildDocument(): Either<Error, IdocsFileInfo>{

    val imageCode = parseCbImageCode()
    val cbId = parseCbFinaidId()

    return parseCbOwner().fold({
        Error(it).left()
    },
        { owner ->

            if( ImageCode.fromImageCode(imageCode) == null)
            {
                Error("$imageCode is not a recognized image code.").left()
            }

            val codeMapping: Map<String, Set<IdocsMapping>> = imageCodeMappings.value()
            val mapping = codeMapping["abc"]?.first { it.owner == owner }
            if (mapping != null) {
                IdocsFileInfo(cbId, mapping).right()
            }
            else
            {
                Error("Unable to determine mapping.").left()
            }
        })
}


The answer it turns out was simple oversight. I forgot to add the .bind() call. The working code looks like:
fun mapServiceDocs(orderedFilesForPerson:List<File>): Either<NonEmptyList<Error>, List<IdocsFileInfo>>{
       return orderedFilesForPerson.mapOrAccumulate<Error, File, IdocsFileInfo>{ file:File->

            file.buildDocument().bind()
        }
}

